# How do I use cx_Freeze on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I used python 3.4 and cx_Freeze on my mac. I was trying to convert my python script into a stand alone application here is the code I got in my setup.py file:

```
application_title = "Death Dodger 1.0" 
main_python_file = "DeathDodger-1.0.py"

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
        name = application_title,
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Sample cx_Freeze script",
        options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes }},
        executables = [Executable(main_python_file, base = base)])
```

I typed in these lines of code into my Terminal:

```
cd /Users/HarryHarlow/Desktop/Death_Dodger
```

and I typed in this line after:

```
python3.4 setup.py bdist_mac
```

I got this error message after long lines of other results:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:       '/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Tcl'
```

Please help, I've been stuck on this for **3 weeks**,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need Tcl you can exclude it in the setup file:

```
application_title = "Death Dodger 1.0" 
main_python_file = "DeathDodger-1.0.py"

import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["atexit","re"]

setup(
    name = application_title,
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Sample cx_Freeze PyQt4 script",
    options = {
        "build_exe" : {
            "includes" : includes
            "excludes": ['tcl', 'ttk', 'tkinter', 'Tkinter'], 
        }
    },
    executables = [
        Executable(main_python_file, base = base)
    ]
)
```

I excluded also Tkinter since as far as I can understand you are making use of PyQt4 to draw the user interface.